# How to access dataverse table without app registration?

Tags: c#, powerapps, power-automate

my problem is that I try to collect data from one of the dataverse table from the c# backend code, but without app registration and getting app id (long business process in my company). Is there any way to achieve using something other than official dataverse web api?

I was trying to use httpClient to send GET requests to the dataverse, as well as DataverseClient nuget package and FetchXMLBuilder. I couldn't connect

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You do need an authenticated and authorized user to access dataverse via its API's (Any modality)

If you have an account to the dataverse instance you are looking to query data from and are authorized in the system to do so, you can create an interactive login via the Dataverse ServiceClient, or set up the same via MSAL (or similar) library and access the API that way.

Headless connections however do require a Client Application ID and either a Client Secret or Client Certificate to connect.